# Syntax concealends not applied

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting

I am developing a syntax file and I am struggling with a `concealends` property :

```
syntax region Reference start="{reference}" end="{/reference}" conceal
syntax region Name start="{name}" end="{/name}" concealends

{name}name1{/name}
{reference}ref{/reference}{name}name2{/name}
```

Then I source the file and the syntax is applied. I run `set conceallevel=2` and I have the following *display* :

```
syntax region Reference start="" conceal
syntax region Name start="{name}" end="{/name}" concealends

{name}name1{/name}
{name}name2{/name}
```

So the conceal property is applied to the `reference` block but the concealends is not.

I tried this with and  without my `vimrc` and the results doesn't change.

Do you have an idea of what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The help (`:syn-concealends`) states:

> The ends of a region can only be concealed separately
>   in this way when they have their own highlighting via "matchgroup"

So I did a little test by using an existing highlight group:

```
syntax region Reference start="{reference}" end="{/reference}" conceal
syntax region Name matchgroup=texStatement start="{name}" end="{/name}" concealends
```

This hides the `{reference}ref{/reference}` completely, and hides the `{name}` and `{/name}` region markers/ends, leaving `name1` and `name2` only - I suppose this is what you aim.

This isn't a complete answer. Hope the above are a good pointer to further reading - I am an absolute beginner in the syntax area.

Comment: oooh, dumb me, I though that the `ends of a region` meant the "closing pattern" only. I didn't try this. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome :) When you feel like knowing all this syntax stuff, perhaps write a blog post ;)

Comment: Definitely! At the first time I tried reading the `:h syntax`, but it got me confused pretty quickly, I also read [LVTHW syntax's section](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/45.html) but it doesn't cover all there is to do.

Comment: Thanks. Just wondered how to conceal `matchgroup`.